# Conditional expectation for bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose
$\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}
\sim N
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix};
\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2&\rho\sigma\\\rho\sigma&1\end{bmatrix}
\right)$. How would I compute the conditional density, distribution and expectation of $X$ conditional on $Y>0$?

My attempt for the density function:
\begin{align*}
f(y|y>0)&=f(y)/P(Y>0)&\\
&=2f(y),\quad &y>0\\
f(x|y>0)&=f(x,y)/f(y|y>0)\\
&=f(x,y)/2f(y),\quad &y>0\\
\end{align*}

Distribution function:
\begin{align*}
F(x|y>0)&=P(X\leq x|Y>0)\\
&=P(X\leq x,Y>0)/P(Y>0)\\
&=\left(\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^yf(u,v)dudv\right)\bigg/\int_0^ \infty f(y)dy
\end{align*}

Expectation:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}(X|Y>0)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x|y>0)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x,y)/2f(y),\quad y>0
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: And what about using the specific features of gaussian families (as was already advocated on this site many times)? Namely, one knows that $X=aY+bZ$ with $a=\sigma\rho$, $a^2+b^2=\sigma^2$, and $Z$ standard normal independent of $Y$, hence $$E(X\mid Y>0)=aE(Y\mid Y>0)+bE(Z)=2aE(Y;Y>0)$$ with $$E(Y;Y>0)=\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}ydy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ The decomposition $X=aY+bZ$ also gives the distribution of $X$ conditioned on the event $[Y>0]$.

Comment: Thank you. I just don't see how $aE(Y|Y>0)+bE(Z)=2aE(Y|Y>0)$. Shouldn't it be $aE(Y|Y>0)$? And how exactly does the distribution of $X$ conditional on $Y>0$ follow from the decomposition?

Comment: Note that $aE(Y\mid Y>0)+bE(Z)=2aE(Y;Y>0)$ because $E(Z)=0$, $P(Y>0)=\frac12$ and $E(Y\mid Y>0)=E(Y;Y>0)/P(Y>0)$ (and that your comment confuses $E(Y\mid Y>0)$ and $E(Y;Y>0)=E(Y\mathbf 1_{Y>0})$).

Comment: I didn't know the notation but I get it now. I still don't see how to find the density or distribution function from the decomposition.

Comment: Surely you will try to work on the decomposition I provided, to get the conditional PDF...